# Flesch-Kincaid readability test in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, flesch-kincaid

I need help with this problem I'm having. I need to write a function that returns a FRES (Flesch reading-ease test) from a text. Given the formula:

[image]

In other words my task is to turn this formula into a python function.

this is the code from the [previous question I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251629/converting-readability-formula-into-python-function/49259380?noredirect=1#comment85541910_49259380):

```
import nltk
import collections
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('gutenberg')
nltk.download('brown')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('universal_tagset')

import re
VC = re.compile('[aeiou]+[^aeiou]+', re.I)
def count_syllables(word):
    return len(VC.findall(word))

from itertools import chain
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
def compute_fres(text):
    """Return the FRES of a text.
    >>> emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw('austen-emma.txt')
    >>> compute_fres(emma) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    99.40...
    """

for filename in gutenberg.fileids():
    sents = gutenberg.sents(filename)
    words = gutenberg.words(filename)
    num_sents = len(sents)
    num_words = len(words)
    num_syllables = sum(count_syllables(w) for w in words)
    score = 206.835 - 1.015 * (num_words / num_sents) - 84.6 * (num_syllables / num_words)
return(score)
```

And this is the result I get:

```
Failure
Expected :99.40...

Actual   :92.84866041488623

**********************************************************************
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/a1/a1.py", line 60, in a1.compute_fres
Failed example:
    compute_fres(emma) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
Expected:
    99.40...
Got:
    92.84866041488623
```

My task is to pass the doctest and result in 99.40...
I'm also not allowed the change the following code since it was given to me with the task itself:

```
import re
VC = re.compile('[aeiou]+[^aeiou]+', re.I)
def count_syllables(word):
    return len(VC.findall(word))
```

I feel like I'm getting close but not sure why I get a different result. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would encourage you not to abbreviate your variable names. Also explicit parentheses would make it easier to read as well. When I first read it (my first glance) I assumed the variable sents was an API call or something. Spell it out.

Answer (score 0):

The three `num_*` variables are all of type `int` (integer).  When you divide integers in most programming languages, you get an integer result, rounded down, for example `14 / 5` produces 2, not 2.8.

Change the calculation to

```
score = 206.835 - 1.015 * (float(num_words) / num_sents) - 84.6 * (num_syllables / float(num_words))
```

When one of the operands in a division is a `float`, the other is also silently converted to a `float` and (exact) floating-point division is performed.  Try `float(14)/2`.

Additionally, your regular expression `VC` does not include 'y' among vowels, and does not consider a group of vowels at the end of a word a syllable.  Both errors undercount the number of syllables, for example `count_syllables("myrtle")` will return 0.