# Returning a FRES (Flesch reading-ease test) of a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, flesch-kincaid

I am trying to implement a python function that returns a Flesch-Kincaid readability test of a text by using this formula from this wiki: [Flesch reading-ease test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests)

I also came across a question with the same objective as I do that was answered: [Converting Readability formula into python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251629/converting-readability-formula-into-python-function)

So by using this as a sort of guide I took a similar approach with my implementation and ended with this as my code:

```
import nltk
import collections
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('gutenberg')
nltk.download('brown')

# DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE BELOW #
import re
VC = re.compile('[aeiou]+[^aeiou]+', re.I)
def count_syllables(word):
    return len(VC.findall(word))

def compute_fres(text):
    """Return the FRES of a text.
    >>> emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw('austen-emma.txt')
    >>> compute_fres(emma) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    99.40...
    """

    tToken = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

    for f in nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids():
        nsents = len(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.sents(f))
        nwords = len(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words(f))
        nsyllables = sum(count_syllables(w) for w in words)
        fres = 206.835 - 1.015 * (nwords / nsents) - 84.6 * (nsyllables / nwords)
    return len(fres.findall(tToken))
```

I then ran the my code and got this error message:

```
Error
**********************************************************************
File "C:/Users/WORLD/PycharmProjects/a1/a1.py", line 54, in a1.compute_fres
Failed example:
    compute_fres(emma) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.4\helpers\pycharm\docrunner.py", line 140, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest a1.compute_fres[1]>", line 1, in <module>
        compute_fres(emma) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
      File "C:/Users/WORLD/PycharmProjects/a1/a1.py", line 63, in compute_fres
        nsyllables = sum(count_syllables(w) for w in words)
    NameError: name 'words' is not defined
```

Like the other user's post, my goal is to pass the doctest by implementing the correct function. I can also assume that he/she is in the same programming class as me.

I'm a bit newby to python so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's not really going to help if you keep creating new questions on the same problem with the same account or a different one ;P (Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/users/7087895/ovaflow)

Comment: Or maybe it's really another person, doing the same homework?

Comment: 1, Namespaces are good, use them (we're not Java). Instead of `import nltk; nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words()`, do this `from nltk.corpus import gutenberg; gutenberg.words()`

Comment: 2. This line here `sum(count_syllables(w) for w in words)`, do you understand what it's doing? If not, a look at list comprehension, https://github.com/usaarhat/pywarmups/blob/master/session2.md

Comment: 3. Why was `tToken` created but not used?

Comment: 4. (not crucial) but BTW, do you know what's `f` in `for f in nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids():`? Explicit is better than implicit (esp. when it comes to naming variables).

Comment: 5. Do you know the type of `fres`? If not, try to `print(type(fres))` after the `fres = 206.835 - ... ` line. Take a look at https://github.com/usaarhat/pywarmups/blob/master/session1.md if you don't know what `type()` does.

Comment: 6. Do you know what `len(fres.findall(tToken))` is trying to do? Do you know where does the `.findall()` come from? And what does `len()` do?

Comment: Hope the questions above helps! Have fun with the `homework`?

Comment: @alvas Thank you for your comments, I did more research into the things you pointed out and they really helped alot. And also I don;t blame you if you thought I was the same guy that posted the similar question before I found it and linked it to mine. But again thank you for your advice, it's bit different going from java to python though